# Does indian passport holder travelling from US to Muscat need transit visa at Heathrow airport

Tags: visas, transit, london

Does indian passport holder travelling back from US to Muscat and has a layover of 9 hours at terminal 5 Heathrow airport need Transit visa(travelling by American airlines